# Updating rows on a table with condition

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to delete all the rows, starting from the bottom of the table using a condition, but when that conditions is met then i want it to stop updating the table and leave the rest as it was. Example, if the last entry on the table meets it, delete it, if the one after it does not meet the condition then stop there, and exite the loop.
Here's the code i got, but its deleting all the rows :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A atualizar dados");
        bool check = true;
        do
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
            string queryString = string.Empty;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab 
                WHERE serie ='1' AND tipodoc ='FSS' 
                AND contribuinte ='999999990' 
                and datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120)"

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                //command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                queryString = "SELECT * FROM wgcdoccab 
                WHERE serie !='1' and tipodoc !='FSS'
                and contribuinte !='999999990' 
                and  datadoc != CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())),120) ";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {

                        check = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("Dados Apagados com sucesso");
                    }
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        while (check);
```

Comment: If you mean the values of what i want to update, it's an int value for example 4

Comment: Its and editing mistake i will fix it

Comment: we need to see the sample values of the table which we could try.

Comment: How do i show you the sample? I'm working remotely on the project right now, cant access the original DB only have a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this example:

```
DELETE
FROM tableName
WHERE ID > 
(
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM tableName
    WHERE condition = false
)
```

For example, if you want to delete until a value is 4:

```
DELETE
FROM tableName
WHERE ID > 
(
    SELECT MAX(ID)
    FROM tableName
    WHERE tableName.Value = 4
)
```

If the table rows are:

```
|ID|Value|
| 1|    7|
| 2|    4|
```

Then the subselect will be 2 and no rows will be deleted.  However, if the rows are:

```
|ID|Value|
| 1|    7|
| 2|    4|
| 3|    9|
| 4|    1|
```

Then the subselect will still return the ID of 2, and the last 2 rows will be deleted.

Comment: I was thinking about something like that, the problem is that this solution will delete all the rows that are within the condition, and i only want to delete starting from the bottom row until the condition is false, then i want to stop deleting and leave the rest original. But thank you

Comment: @LesterNotTheMolestor What do you mean by "within the condition"?  This solution will "delete starting from the bottom row until the condition is false"

Comment: Yes it makes sense, im really sorry for not answering sooner, im really tired i will edit the code tomorrow and reply to you, but it is doing what i want thank you so much @KyleW

Comment: @LesterNotTheMolestor Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.